# How to set Page Break Preview?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically set my page break preview.

I tried

```
Worksheets("Stack").Range("A2:M33").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

I get

> Unable to set Pagebreak Property of the range Class

Comment: weird, that works perfectly fine for me

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 , i dont even think this is the correct excel function, i think it should be xlpagebreakpreview I am looking for. Still, doesnt work though.

Comment: Is your `ActiveWindow.Vew` set to `xlPageBreakPreview` ? https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/304667-vba-page-break-problems.html

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 yes it is, I tried that posts suggestions such as putting it to normal view, page break preview, resetting page breaks, none are allowing my statement to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's almost two years late, but just not to leave this unanswered. I did the following:

```
Dim WSh As Worksheet, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set WSh = Sheets("Stack")
    Set Rng1 = Range("A5")
    Set Rng2 = Range("N34")

WSh.ResetAllPageBreaks
    'From
    If Rng1.Row <> 1 Then WSh.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Rng1
    If Rng1.Column <> 1 Then WSh.VPageBreaks.Add before:=Rng2
    'To
    WSh.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Rng2
    WSh.VPageBreaks.Add before:=Rng2
```

That worked. You would just need to ensure some handling when you manage column "A" or row "1", but that can be easily sorted out with a couple Ifs.

Comment: Thanks Felipe! Better late than never!